# C++: error C2678: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const SPoint'

Tags: c++

This is my code:

```
#include <StdAfx.h>;
#include <iostream>;
#include <vector>;
#include <algorithm>;
#include <iterator>;

using namespace std;
struct SPoint
{
    int id;
    int X;
    int Y;
};

bool operator<(const SPoint& p1, const SPoint&p2){
    return p1.id <p2.id;
}

vector<SPoint> points;
vector<SPoint> chosen;
vector<SPoint> cleared;

vector<SPoint>::iterator it;

void print_vect(const vector<SPoint> & vect)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < vect.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << vect[i].id << " (" << vect[i].X << "," << vect[i].Y << ")"<<endl;               
    }           

    cout << endl;   
}
bool compare(double val1, double val2)
{
    return val1 > val2;
}
void sort_points(const vector<SPoint> & vect, char command)
{
    bool cmp_result;
    SPoint temp;
    bool sorted=true;
    for (int i = 0; i < vect.size()-1 ; i++)
    {
        sorted=true;
        for (int j = 1; j <= vect.size()-1; j++)
        {
            switch (command) 
            {
                case 'x': 
                    {
                        cmp_result = compare(vect[j-1].X, vect[j].X); 
                        break;
                    }
                case 'y': 
                    {
                        cmp_result = compare(vect[j-1].Y, vect[j].Y); 
                        break;              
                    }               
                case 'i': 
                    {
                        cmp_result = compare(vect[j-1].id, vect[j].id); 
                        break;              
                    }           
            }

            if (cmp_result)
            {
                sorted = false;
                temp = vect[j-1];
                vect[j-1] = vect[j];
                vect[j] = temp;
            }

        }
        if (sorted) 
        {
            cout << "Sorted:" << endl;
            print_vect(vect);           
            break;
        }
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    SPoint temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        temp.id = i;
        temp.X = i;
        temp.Y = i;
        points.push_back(temp);
    }

    for (int i = 5; i < 10; i++)
    {
        temp.id = i;
        temp.X = i;
        temp.Y = i;
        chosen.push_back(temp);
    }

    cout << "Points:" << endl;
    print_vect(points);
    cout << endl << endl;

    cout << "Chosen:" << endl;
    print_vect(chosen);

    system("pause");
    sort_points(points, 'i');
    sort_points(chosen, 'i');
    set_difference(points.begin(), points.end(), chosen.begin(), chosen.end(), back_inserter(cleared));
    print_vect(cleared);

    return 0;
}
```

Can anybody help me to understand why I am having these errors:

```
1>c:\users\гость\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\grablevskij2\grablevskij2\grablevskij2.cpp(110): error C2678: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const SPoint' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          c:\users\гость\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\grablevskij2\grablevskij2\grablevskij2.cpp(18): could be 'SPoint &SPoint::operator =(const SPoint &)'
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(const SPoint, const SPoint)'
1>c:\users\гость\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\grablevskij2\grablevskij2\grablevskij2.cpp(111): error C2678: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const SPoint' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          c:\users\гость\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\grablevskij2\grablevskij2\grablevskij2.cpp(18): could be 'SPoint &SPoint::operator =(const SPoint &)'
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(const SPoint, SPoint)'
```

Comment: гость, your example is too long. Try reducing it the the minimum. You can delete about 95% of this example to get the same error. It's a skill worth developing, and helps you help yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `sort_points` function, you declared `vect` as `const`. Later, you say:

```
vect[j-1] = vect[j];
vect[j] = temp;
```

Since `vect` is `const`, this causes the `const` version of `operator[]` to be called, which returns a `const` reference to the object, which is not assignable.

Seeing as how it's named `sort_points` and does not return a new vector, I would expect it to modify the vector I pass in.